# How can I assign a Variable to a "Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sid)"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Dear friends,

I want to assign a variable to a "item.StaffId" such as int a ;
How can I do that?

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StaffId)
</td>
```

Thank You!!

Regards,
Keon

Comment: From View or controller?

Comment: from view @J.SMTBCJ15

Comment: You may assign model properties with view-only variable such like `Model.StaffId = a`, but more preferred to use controller action method instead.

Comment: Thanks! I want to do something like this 

        <td>
            @String abc = (modelItem => item.StaffId);
            <span>@abc</span>
        </td>

Comment: i know la , sorry to ask a simple question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@{
     int number;
     number = item.StaffId;
}
```